# Does realtime light or baked light consume more ram?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lightning

I want to improve the performance of my game. I've done many things and there have been drastic changes in performance. I also want to change the light. but I don't know which light is more performance friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what type of lighting you are trying to do.

Baked lighting is stored in textures, so require a bit of ram, but it is fairly cheap to render, and allow for very complex light, as long as it is all static.

A single omni directional non-shadow casting light would not require any extra memory, just a fairly simple light calculation in the shader, so would be very cheap. But once you add more lights, shadows, global illumination etc, the cost goes up drastically, and you would typically need to apply various optimizations to get decent performance.This is just general recommendations that is non unity specific.

In unity you should have various settings for the lights that affect the quality of the lighting and performance. If you do not know where to start I would suggest starting with baked light, and adding realtime lights where needed, and be careful with things like realtime global illumination since that is a really difficult problem to solve.